# Gnome shell and Unity do not display tootips in system tray icon (Qt)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, system-tray

There are no tooltips displayed when mouse hovers on tray icon.

```
 trayIcon->setToolTip(str);
```

does not work. I figured out an alternative way for Gnome:

```
 curpos = QCursor::pos();
    QRect rect;
    rect = trayIcon->geometry();
    if(rect.contains(curpos))
    {
         QToolTip::showText(rect.center(),"hello",this);
    }
```

But in Unity shell

```
rect = trayIcon->geometry();
```

returns (0,0,0×0) always. So can anyone suggest any alternative method, which i can use in Unity Shell.